# How to assign value to a state inside a map function of a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

Tried to pass a clicked type value of a card and what I want to get is the type of that card. **state.memoryCards** outputs the following in the log:

- 0: {name: "Aircraft", type: "200", maxSpeed: 880, imageName: "a1", …}
- 1: {name: "Aircraft", type: "300", maxSpeed: 880, imageName: "a2", …}
- 2: {name: "Aircraft", type: "200ER", maxSpeed: 920 imageName: "a8", …}
- 3: {name: "Aircraft", type: "300ER", maxSpeed: 920 imageName: "a9", …}

As you might see the **state.currentCardType = card.type** is not a good habit, since the state is being mutated. So therefore I want to refactor the code, but not sure how to write that, because it is inside a map function.

```js
case types.CARD_CHECK: {
            return {
                ...state,
                memoryCards: state.memoryCards.map((card, index) => {
                    console.log(state.memoryCards)
                    if(index === action.index) {
                        
                        state.currentCardType = card.type;  <---- I am talking about this on
  
                        return {
                            ...card,
                            flipped: !card.flipped
                        }
                    }

                    return card
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: return { ...state, currentCardType: state.memoryCards[action.id].type, memoryCards: ...}

Comment: What did you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can derive modified `memoryCards` first and then `currentCardType` separately like this

```
 case types.CARD_CHECK: {
    let memoryCards = state.memoryCards.map((card, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
            return {
                ...card,
                flipped: !card.flipped
            }
        }
        return card
    });

    let currentCardType = state.memoryCards[action.index].type; // since your are checking array index with action.index

    return {
        ...state,
        memoryCards,
        currentCardType
    }
}
```

Comment: But currentCardType is a state in this case

Comment: `currentCardType` is part of state right? like `memoryCards`?

Comment: yes it is inside the state.memoryCards. const initialState = {currentcardType: [] }

Comment: I guess you mean its part of different reducer?

Comment: Then what i have given should work. have you tried it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196003/discussion-between-frontend-and-ashish).